# iPhone Push Notifications Problems With iPhone sending

Tags: php, iphone, vb.net, mobile, push-notification

I'm trying to send iPhone push notifications ideally via VB.Net, although I can send them via PHP.
I have tried both methods (which works fine for Android) but they fail for iPhone (ios).

Here is the code I have been using and the problems I get:

VB.Net

```
Dim appleCert As Byte()
appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\AppleAppKey\aps_development.p12")
push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(appleCert, "123xxx321"))
push.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification() _ .ForDeviceToken("06611dd37b6e0fff87da9edd8j97ddf337246274e0dd3a77fc7d7a14") _
    .WithAlert("Hello World!") _
    .WithBadge(7) _
    .WithCustomItem("content-available", 1))
```

> ERROR: NO Error returned but no notification is sent to the phone.

PHP

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', self::$passphrase); 
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60,STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
```

> ERROR:  stream_socket_client() SSL: The specified procedure could not be found.

I have created an Apple Developer account and created .pem .p12 .cer files.
I have also tested the Apple connection via telnet

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert ios_development.pem -key aps_development.pem  -CAfile entrust_2048_ca.cer
```

and this works.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to recreate the notification SSL again (third time) and it worked fine.

Hard going when I can't see any feedback from apple servers to say the initial ssl certs were rejected.